# Yii2 - Use dataProvider multiple times with different sorting

Tags: php, yii2

So I have a dataprovider which is created in a controller like this:

```
$modelSearch = new SearchModel();
$data_provider = $modelSearch->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams); // returns the data provider
```

Then I use the $data_provider in a view like this:

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $data_provider,
    'export'       => false,
    'columns'      => [
        ...
    ],
...
```

But now I'd like to use the **same data** from the $data_provider **but without pagination and other sorting specifications**.

Tried this but doesn't work:

```
$data_provider->sort = ['defaultOrder'=> ['column_a' => SORT_ASC, 'column_b' => SORT_DESC]]
$data_provider->pagination = false;
```

I think that's because the data is already retrieved with the `->search()` method. Do I need to create a whole new search model class? just to get a different sorting?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I asked the question I didn't know the dataProvider already retrieved the data on creation. So altering properties of the dataProvider doesn't do another search, it does different sorting but with the same data it already retrieved.

***Answer*:**
I ended up making a new method in the searchModel class like this:

```
public function searchByCreatedAt() {
    $query = Model::find()->orderBy(['created_at' => SORT_ASC]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => false,
    ]);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use two dataProvider  eg:

```
$modelSearch = new SearchModel();
$data_provider = $modelSearch->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

$data_provider2 = $data_provider;
$data_provider2->pagination = false; 
$data_provider2->sort = ['defaultOrder'=> ['column_a' => SORT_ASC, 'column_b' => SORT_DESC]]


 return $this->render('your_view', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $data_provider,
        'dataProvider2' => $data_provider2,
    ]);
```

Comment: I will try this immediately tomorrow! If it works I'll accept your answer.

Comment: It didn't work like I wanted it. I asked the question wrong by saying I wanted to work with the same data (I wanted to use the same search). I think the sorting worked but the data was still the same as the first dataProvider. That's because it filled the dataProvider on the moment he does "$modelSearch->search($params)" and not on the moment you use the $dataProvider (eg. $dataProvider->getModels()). I ended up making a new search method "$modelSearch->customSearch()" which gives another dataprovider. Thank you anyway for the answer, but I can't accept it.